# настройка pptpd на авторизацию с шифрованием и без

Tags: linux, ppp, pptp

Нужно настроить pptpd так чтоб принимались и шифрованные и нешифрованные соединения. Проблема в том что когда убираю опцию require-mppe перестают подключаться клиенты с шифрованием, а если её оставить то нешифрованные не могут присоединиться.

Comment: Это все так плохо как описывают ? http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/protocol-security.phtml Может поискать альтернативу? StrongSwan/OpenVPN/WireGuard ?

Comment: вот думаю об айписеке без шифрования)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставил `accel-ppp`. С настройками почти по умолчанию принимает соединения без проблем.

Answer (score 3):

Увы. Только [патчить pppd](https://habr.com/post/56496/).

Выдержка из README.MPPE:

> if you turn it on, all other compression options are disabled and MPPE
>   *must* be negotiated successfully in both directions (CCP is unidirectional) or the link will be disconnected. I think this is
>   reasonable since, if you want encryption, you want encryption. That
>   is, I am not convinced that optional encryption is useful.